# How can I get all entity names (collection names) from a RavenDB database?

Tags: c#, collections, metadata, document, ravendb

I need retrieve all RavenDB collection names present into a database. Is there any way to do this? How?

Comment: what type of web searches have you tried on your own Lucas..?

Comment: here is a good start Lucas start reading the documentation located here [Beginner's Guide to RavenDB](http://www.w3enterprises.com/articles/beginner-guide-to-ravendb.aspx)

Comment: I tried create an index with Map = docs => from doc in docs
                           select new
                           {
                               Name = MetadataFor(doc).Value<string>("Raven-Entity-Name")
                           }; and I performed a LINQ searching selecting but didn't work :( I even don't know if this is correct way

Comment: Look at this link Lucas - http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/theory/ravendb-collections

Comment: Well... but how to use this to retrive names using LINQ? I've tried many ways and didn't work. Example: from doc in session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<dynamic>("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName")
                            select doc.Tag ...

Comment: Lucas that site gives you the Linq examples you will need to start doing web searches i.e use [Google](http://www.google.com)

Comment: If I don't have tried with such examples and don't have searched over Google.com I would not come here ask someone. I've tried these examples and they didn't work. Why people have always to send me links to docs? I read documentations. I ask for help only when I can't do this by myself! Why is so hard provide me an example here?  Thanks for help.

Comment: I understand your frustration, but without any examples *in the question itself* of what you've tried, and where you've looked, it just looks like you've made no effort at all. Emphasis on *looks*. Edit your question, add the details of what you've done to make it more complete. =)

Comment: Alright! I almost got with this following LINQ query! The query is returning all entities of certain type. I need use DISTINCT to select entity name just one time: var DOC = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<dynamic>()
                           .SelectFields<dynamic>("@metadata"); This query produces: {object[20]}
    [0]: {
  "__document_id": "Users/lucas0",
  "@metadata": {
    "Raven-Entity-Name": "RavenDBMembershipUsers",
    "Raven-Clr-Type": "RavenDB.Providers.RavenDBMembershipUser, RavenDB.Providers",
    "Temp-Index-Score": 1.0
  }
}... and so on...

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed.  This is something that others have asked about, and can be useful to many others.

Comment: I know why was closed: because I'm wasn't especific enough about my doubt. I didn't put an example of what I've tried. But the question is so explicative itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've used the studio at all, you'll see it created an index called `Raven/DocumentsByEntityName`.  If you don't use the studio, or you want to ensure it's there, you can build it yourself with:

```
documentStore.ExecuteIndex(new RavenDocumentsByEntityName());
```

The way that Raven Studio builds it's "collections" list is by getting the terms of the `Tag` field from this index.  You can do the same thing:

```
var results = documentStore.DatabaseCommands
                           .GetTerms("Raven/DocumentsByEntityName", "Tag", "", 1024);
```

*(If you expect more than 1024 different entity types for some reason, then paginate.)*

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get to this sooner.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got a solution by trying with my knowledges acquired learning documentation previously. I would want to advert people I only come here when I'm exausted with tentatives.

```
public string[] getCollectionNames()
        {
            using (var session = this.store.OpenSession())
            {
                return session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<dynamic>()
                           .SelectFields<dynamic>("@metadata")
                           .Select<dynamic, string>(x => x["@metadata"]["Raven-Entity-Name"])
                           .Distinct()
                           .ToArray();

            }
        }
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that the `Distinct` runs client-side.  So you have to return a lot excess data before getting the result you want.

Comment: Distinct runs server side, actually. At least when you do that using the Linq API.
Using Lucene API, this is indeed running client side.
But this isn't going to work, and the other option is much better

Comment: This works. Just this option isn't better as you told. But it works because I tested. How I would know that LuceneQuery Distinct runs in client? Is this in documentation?